# Oracle SQL null row order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

| Name |
| --- |
| (null) |
| Name1 |
| Name2 |
| Name3 |
| (null) |
| Name4 |

I would like to generate this output:

| Name | Output |
| --- | --- |
| (null) | Anon1 |
| Name1 | Name1 |
| Name2 | Name2 |
| Name3 | Name3 |
| (null) | Anon2 |
| Name4 | Name4 |

With the below query, I'm able to generate the below table

```
WITH aux ( name ) AS (
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Name1'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Name2'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Name3'
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Name4'
    FROM
        dual
)
SELECT
    a.*,
    nvl(name, concat('Anon', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY name
        ORDER BY
            ROWNUM
    ))) output
FROM
    aux a;
```

| Name | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | Name1 |
| Name2 | Name2 |
| Name3 | Name3 |
| Name4 | Name4 |
| (null) | Anon1 |
| (null) | Anon2 |

However, the nulls appear at the end instead of the original order. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: What is the first query ordering by?  If you run a query without an `order by`, the order of the results is arbitrary.  It can and will change over time.  If you have a dependency on the order of the results, you'd need to have some other column to order by.

Comment: @Martin excuse me about the comment I wrote for your answer please . I think I didn't pick the right word as a non-native speaker. (I'll delete this comment,using this as just a communication way, I can also delete that comment if you resurrect the answer ). Just wanted to express you were not right. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies that ordering.  Without a column that specifies the ordering of the rows, your question does not make sense.

If I assume that you have an ordering column, then you can do:

```
select name,
       coalesce(name,
                'anon' || row_number() over (partition by name order by <ordering col>
               ) as output
from aux
order by <ordering col>;
```

Comment: So the initial rownum is not fixed? Does rownum change dynamically?

Comment: @JaviTorre . . . `rownum` is a sequential value that enumerates the results of a query; it is not part of the table.  In a query without an `order by`, the results are indeterminate and can change even from one execution to the next.